# Lagom PersistentEntityRef

Tags: lagom

I am studying Lagom and try to understand how persistent entities work.

I've read the following description:

> Every PersistentEntity has a fixed identifier (primary key) that can
>   be used to fetch the current state and at any time only one instance
>   (as a “singleton”) is kept in memory.

Makes sense.

Then there is the following example to create a customer:

```
@Override
public ServiceCall<CreateCustomerMessage, Done> createCustomer() {
   return request -> {
       log.info("===> Create or update customer {}", request.toString());
       PersistentEntityRef<CustomerCommand> ref = persistentEntityRegistry.refFor(CustomerEntity.class, request.userEmail);
       return ref.ask(new CustomerCommand.AddCustomer(request.firstName, request.lastName, request.birthDate, request.comment));
   };
}
```

This confuses me:

- Does that mean that the persistentEntityRegistry contain multiple singleton persistentEntities? How exactly does the persistentEntityRegistry get filled and what is in it? Say we have 10k users that are created, does the registry contain 10k persistentEntities, or just 1?
- In this case we want to create a new customer. So when we request a persistentEntity using `persistentEntityRegistry.refFor(CustomerEntity.class, request.userEmail);`, this shouldn't return anything from the registry since the customer doesn't exist yet (?).

Can you shine a light on how this works? 
Documentation is good but there a few holes in my understanding that I haven't been able to fill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great questions. I'm not sure how far you are along with concepts relating to persistent entities that aren't mentioned here, so I'll start from the beginning.

When doing event sourcing, generally, for a given entity (eg, a single customer), you need a single writer. This is because generally reading and then writing to the event log is not done in a single transaction, so you read some events to load your state, validate an incoming command, and then emit one or more new events to be persisted. If two operations came in for the same entity at the same time, then they would both be validated with the same state - not taking into account the state change that the other might get in before they are executed. Hence, event sourcing requires a single writer principle, only one operation can be handled at a time so there's only one writer.

In Lagom, this is implemented using actors. Each entity (ie each instance of a customer) is loaded and managed by an actor. An actor has a mailbox (ie, a queue), where commands are placed, and it processes them one at a time, in order. For each entity, there is a singleton actor managing it (so, one actor per customer, many actors for many customers). Due to the single writer principle, it's very important that this is true.

But, how does a system like this scale? What happens if you have multiple nodes, do you then have multiple instances of each entity? No. Lagom uses Akka clustering with Akka cluster sharding to shard your entities across many nodes, ensuring that across all of your deployed nodes, you only have one of each entity. So when a command comes in to a node, the entity may live on the same node, in which case it just gets sent straight to the local actor for it to be processed, or it may live on a different node, in which case it gets serialised, sent to the node it lives on, and processed there, with the response being serialised and sent back.

This is one of the reasons why it's a `PersistentEntityRef`, due to the location transparency (you don't know where the entity lives), you can't hold onto the entity directly, you can only have a reference to it. The same terminology is used for actors, you have the actual `Actor` that does the behaviour, and an `ActorRef` is used to communicate with it.

Now, logically, when you get a reference for a customer that according to the domain model of your system doesn't exist yet (eg, they haven't registered), they don't exist. But, the persistent entity for them can, and must exist. There is actually no concept in Lagom of a persistent entity not existing, you can always instantiate a persistent entity of any id, it will load. It's just that there might be no events yet for that entity, in which case, when it loads, it will just have its `initialState`, with no events applied. For a customer, the state of the customer might be `Optional<Customer>`. So, when the entity is first created before any events are emitted for a customer, the state will be `Optional.empty()`. The first event emitted for the customer will be a `CustomerRegistered` event, and this will cause the state to change to an `Optional.of(someCustomer)`.

To understand why logically this must be so, you don't want the same customer to be able to register themselves twice, right? You want to ensure that there is only one `CustomerRegistered` event for each customer. To do that, you need to have a state for the customer in their unregistered state, to validate that they are not already registered before they do register.

So, to make clear the answer to your first question, if you have 10K users, then there will be 10K persistent entity instances, one for each user. Though, that is only logically (there will be events for 10K different users in the database physically). In memory, the actual loaded entities will depend on which entities are active, when an entity goes for, by default, 2 minutes without receiving a command, Lagom will passivate that entity, that means, it drops it from memory, so the next time a command comes in for it will have to be loaded by loading the events for it from the database. This helps to ensure that you don't run out of memory by holding all your data in memory if you don't want.

Comment: That clarifies it thanks. Perhaps one more additional question: you probably don't want to maintain 1k customers in memory all the time. When are the entities removed from memory? Should we configure this or does it happen automatically? Very clear explanations btw.

Comment: That's addressed in my last paragraph - they get removed from memory when passivated, which by default is after 2 minutes of inactivity. The docs for this are here: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/PersistentEntity.html and the configuration option is lagom.persistence.passivate-after-idle-timeout